# Spotify: how to make playlist items clickable?

Tags: spotify

I'm making a Spotify app which makes a default-style playlist as demonstrated in the api-tutorial.

However, the elements in the list are not clickable links like they are in the regular Spotify tracks list.

How do I make the playlist "active" so that clicking on an album name for example will take you to the page for that album.  (or artist etc)?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

Links to Spotify entities work the same as normal links, but the `href` attribute has the value of a Spotify URI. Here you have some examples:

```html
<!-- link for an artist -->
<a href="spotify:artist:4F84IBURUo98rz4r61KF70">The White Stripes</a>

<!-- link for an album -->
<a href="spotify:album:748dZDqSZy6aPXKcI9H80u">good kid, m.A.A.d city</a>

<!-- link for a track -->
<a href="spotify:track:5h5tBFnbcVioFXiOixTn6E">Bitch, Don't Kill My Vibe</a>

<!-- link for a playlist -->
<a href="spotify:user:nurilla:playlist:2Uog3C32oF7px4JFHpuGtJ">Divos que son divinos</a>

<!-- link for a user -->
<a href="spotify:user:jrufi91">Julio</a>
```

There are examples of this in the [Spotify App Tutorial](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial), running the example called *[Return metadata with a given search query](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/search/search.html)*.

You can also navigate to a certain page using Javascript, using the [`openURI`](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-application.html#openURI) function:

```js
models.application.openURI('spotify:artist:4F84IBURUo98rz4r61KF70');
```

The Spotify URI can be obtained right-clicking on the entity, and selecting "Copy Spotify URI".